# Compiling java code

Tags: java, netbeans

I wrote some code with Netbeans some time ago. I ended up moving the code to a new server, which I access remotely and does not have netbeans installed. I recently made some changes to that code and compiled with this command

```
javac -classpath /home/me/JSAP-2.1.jar /home/me/Fin2/src/fin2/Fin2.java  /home/me/Fin2/src/fin2/CommandLine.java /home/me/Fin2/src/fin2/Reader.java /home/me/Fin2/src/fin2/Manager.java -Xlint
```

But it seems like the new code never compiled. I am getting the same output as before I made the changes.
When I have previously ran across this problem on the old server, I would just open netbeans and reset the 'main project' to the program I was trying to run, recompile from within netbeans and it would work fine. Without doing that, I have no idea how to fix the problem.

When I run the code I run it with

```
 java -jar /home/me/NetBeansProjects/Fin2/dist/Fin2.jar [commandline args]
```

Can anyone make any suggestions?

Comment: Do you run the code from a JAR file and you need to JAR the contents for usage?

Comment: What is not working.  What is the output?  Does it create a .class files?

Comment: As hinted at by the Chris Cooper comment, it appears that your problem is not in the compilation of the java files, but in the packaging of the compiled class files.  The command you show compiles the classes.  Your problem seems likely to be in how you are running the compiled classes.  If you are attempting to run from a jar file, then the problem is that you are not rebuild the jar file.

Comment: @DMoses I have .class files. By not working I mean, if I add or remove a print statement, for example, that change is not being reflected when I attempt to rerun my code.

Comment: If you are generating .class files, then the compile IS working, and the issue most likely lies in how you are running those .class files (maybe you need to jar them up and put them somewhere else?)

Comment: @DMoses I am not sure what you mean. Could you submit an answer but with more details?

Comment: @Stephopolis you need to show how you are trying to run the code.

Comment: @DMoses java -jar /home/me/NetBeansProjects/Fin2/dist/Fin2.jar [commandline args] ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a step that your IDE does for you.  You will need to create the `jar` file from the class file output.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html

Since you are not adding a -d the class files are in the directory of the source files.  Lets actually add a compiled output directory

```
rm -r /home/me/Fin2/build/
mkdir /homr/me/Fin2/build/
```

Now lets add that folder to the javac, so the classes are created in that folder:

```
javac -Xlint -d /home/me/Fin2/build/ -classpath /home/me/JSAP-2.1.jar /home/me/Fin2/src/fin2/Fin2.java  /home/me/Fin2/src/fin2/CommandLine.java /home/me/Fin2/src/fin2/Reader.java /home/me/Fin2/src/fin2/Manager.java
```

Last we need a jar of that output.  The jar file is basically just a zip of the directory.  In fact, you can open .jar files as zip files.  You must also tell it what class has your main method entry point.

```
jar cvfe /home/me/Fin2/dist/Fin2.jar [entry point] /home/me/Fin2/build/
```

Now, when you run it, run the newly created jar:

```
java -jar /home/me/Fin2/dist/Fin2.jar [commandline args]
```

Comment: This series of steps doesn't seem to be working for me.               The final step returns 'no main manifest attribute, in /home/me/Fin2/dist/Fin2.jar'

Comment: updated to include the entry point in the JAR command.  You can also use a custom manifest instead of the one generated by the jar command.